# Discord.py Error when trying to edit embed after X seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So, after like an hour of trying I gave up. I was trying to make my embed get edited after 5 seconds but it did not work. I keep getting this error:

''Instance of 'Embed' has no 'message' member''

```
import discord
import random
import asyncio
import time
from discord.ext import commands


class ppsize(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command(aliases=['mypp', 'sizepp'])
    async def PPPSize(self, ctx):
        responses = [ # Or values, however you want to name it
        'is 2cm.',
        'is 38cm.',
        'is 0cm.',
        'is too small to be measured.',
        '-16cm.',
        'bigger than a whole house.',
        '6cm.',
        'is 9cm',
        'is 13cm'
    ]
        pp = discord.Embed(title="Activating PP Size Measurement...!", description="Loading PP Size...")
        pp.set_image(url="https://tul.imgix.net/content/article/banana.jpg?auto=format,compress&w=1200&h=630&fit=crop")
        pp2 = discord.Embed(title="PP Size Measurement Has Been Activated!", description=random.choice(responses))
        pp2.set_image(url="https://tul.imgix.net/content/article/banana.jpg?auto=format,compress&w=1200&h=630&fit=crop")
        
        await ctx.send(embed=pp)
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await pp.message.edit(embed=pp2)



def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(ppsize(client))
```

Pretty basic command but no clue what to do. Also do I need the 'Import time'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to edit the embed instead of the actual posted message.

```
await pp.message.edit(embed=pp2)
```

is referring to the embed. That embed doesn't have an attribute called 'message', hence the error.

To fix this:

```
message = await ctx.send(embed=pp)
await asyncio.sleep(5)
await message.edit(embed=pp2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `pp` variable is an embed, it doesn't have the `message` attribute. To get the message instance you can assign when sending it

```py
message = await ctx.send(embed=pp)
await asyncio.sleep(5)
await message.edit(embed=pp2)
```

*PS: Hello again*

#### Reference:

- [`Messageable.send`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=messageable%20send#discord.abc.Messageable.send)
- [`Message.edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=edit#discord.Message.edit)

Comment: Thank you so much again! such an easy fix still could not do it alone... Well gotta be a bit more careful next time. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

`pp.message.edit(embed=pp2)` is saying Embed.message.edit() but as your error suggests: there is no message attribute on embeds.

To replace the embed on a message, you need to get the message that was originally sent.

```
message = await ctx.send(...)
await message.edit(embed=pp2)
```

Comment: You're missing a few things in your answer. For one, a ```ctx.send()``` command requires an ```await``` statement. I'm assuming you've mixed ```ctx.message``` and ```ctx.send()``` up?

Comment: yes, I mixed up `ctx.message` and the new message associated with `ctx.send`. I have edited to clarify. Thanks!